# My class bunked lectures!

Tags: engineering

My class decided to bunk today's lectures. Because there is so much chaos in my city due to heavy rain and blockage. Many student can not come and some of them are not coming due to their parents not allowing them to go. So we executed our plan.

Now, our class teacher want us to meet HOD and take permission from him and then only we are allowed to sit in next lectures.

So, my question is how should we handle this situation?
How should we put ourselves in front of him?

Comment: This is what happens when you think you know the rules of the game. You made a plan and executed it, now the consequence is a meeting with the HoD... Better make sure you all get your story straight... So, don't forget that the teacher and HoD may already have been told or given (social media) the story...

Comment: I suggest humility and remorse. Your "plan" was flawed.

Comment: Did you at least let the teacher/the HoD/anyone know that "sorry, due to the severe wheather conditions, many of us can't come in today"? Or did you just decide among yourself that you will skip, so that the teacher fought his way through the storm to be a good teacher to his students, just to see that they decided to bail on him? In the latter case, I could fully understand why he isn't entirely happy right now.

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to attend lectures?

Comment: Please explain HOD.

Comment: "parents not allowing them to go" -- How old are you and your classmates?

Comment: @user111388 I assume "HOD" means "head of department" here (though to me it normally means "hereditarily ordinal definable")

Comment: @shoover we are 19 year old, but condition in some part of city is really bad, so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preparation for meeting the HoD will depend on the individual student's situation.

Students who attempted to warn the teacher of their non-attendance should document their efforts to do so.

Students who really could not attend should document the road closures and transit cancellations that prevented them from attending.

Minors who were told to stay home by their parents should get a note from the parents taking responsibility and explaining their reasons for keeping the student home.

Anyone who did not attend without a good reason needs to think about the wording of an appropriate apology.

Students who could not attend and made at least some effort to notify the teacher are in the strongest position. Even those should be apologetic about the group non-attendance if they encouraged it.

At the other extreme, I don't see anything other than an apology for a student who could have attended, chose not to, and made no attempt to notify the teacher.

Comment: What about the students who organized the mutiny? Flogged? Or an extra assignment?

Comment: @SolarMike I think their best strategy is an apology, with promise of no repeat.

Comment: Years ago, I did the reverse, snow blocked all the students coming in except me as I walked. Reason was if I did not attend college I would loose a day’s wages... The lecturer was **not** pleased to see me... marked me present and told me to go home..  10 miles there and back :)

Answer (score 0):

> our class teacher want that we should meet HOD and take permission from him and then only we are allowed to sit in next lectures.

Your teacher wants* you to meet the HOD, so meet the HOD.

<sup>*Given the context it seems the teacher has *demanded*, rather than merely *wants*.</sup>

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @user111388 Perhaps you can elaborate on why.